# Bash - create alias that runs task in background AND carries on running other tasks

Tags: bash, alias

My aim is to have an alias that will run commands like this:

```
alias thing="task_1 & && task_2"
```

The point being that task_1 is a long running task and should be started before task_2 but ultimately both should be running at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `task1 & task2` but using functions is generally better for more complicated things like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If both should be running at the same time, then && is probably not what you want to use. It waits for the exit of the first command and executes the second only if the first was successful. With the backgrounding of the first task, this doesn't really make sense.

I tend to do what you're up to this way:

```
    alias thing="(sleep 5 &); sleep 1;"
```

(The parenthesis have a side effect that I like: You don't get the notifications about the process being forked or reaped.)